# 10% bottom text on video

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set some text on video, but nothing good.

My expected result is:
[image]

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg" id="home">
        <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2013-08/small_watermarked/hd0983_preview.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<h2>
text on video
</h2>
```

my script code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/su21Lx35/6/

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS. You can adjust the size according to your preference.

```
h2{
   color: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 90%;
   left: 40%;
}
```